# Animated UIButtons snap back to original position after opening UIAlertView

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, uialertview

I am making a Welcome screen with two UITextFields, a Forgot Password button and two additional buttons (`signInButton` and `createAccountButton`). These two buttons are placed in an UIView (`inputsView`) along with the text fields.

As soon as one of the text fields is focused, I animate the screen to adjust for the keyboard, resize the `createAccountButton` button and slide in the `signInButton`. I'm using the following code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.48 delay:0 usingSpringWithDamping:1 initialSpringVelocity:.42 options:(UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState) animations:^{

    CGRect f3 = inputsView.frame;
    f3.origin.y = 112;
    inputsView.frame = f3;

    [inputsView layoutSubviews];

    CGRect f4 = createAccountButton.bounds;
    f4.size.width = 160;
    createAccountButton.bounds = f4;

    CGRect f5 = createAccountButton.frame;
    f5.origin.x = 160;
    createAccountButton.frame = f5;

    CGRect f6 = signInButton.frame;
    f6.origin.x = 0;
    signInButton.frame = f6;

    CGRect f7 = buttonSeparator.frame;
    f7.origin.x = 160;
    buttonSeparator.frame = f7;

    [signInButton layoutSubviews];
    [createAccountButton layoutSubviews];

} completion:nil];
```

This all works fine, but if I then tap the Forgot Password button to open a UIAlertView, the buttons pop back to their original positions. Strangely enough, the `buttonSeparator`, which is a 1px UIView does not snap back.

Am I forgetting something, or is this a bug in the iOS 7 SDK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you are using *autolayout*

Disable the autolayout property.

Reason why its happening : Autolayout will update the views to their original position using current constraints.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I wanted to use autolayout but I actually didn't use it.